# How to use multiple JDBC drivers in the same application?

Tags: java, jdbc

As far as I understand, as soon as I execute

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

I initialize the application to use JTDS SQL Server driver globally and

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

returns SQL Server connections all after that.

But what if I want to work with multiple different database engines in the same function, getting a JTDS SQL Server connection, then, for example a PostgreSQL connection and then a new JTDS SQL Server connection again?

Comment: is your application JEE or standalone Java?

Comment: Standalone Java (Scala, actually) @user1428716

Comment: from JDBC 4.0 spec : "The `DriverManager` class works with the `Driver` interface to manage the set of
drivers available to a JDBC client. When the client requests a connection and
provides a URL, the DriverManager is responsible for finding a driver that
recognizes the URL and using it to connect to the corresponding data source."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You misunderstand. When you load a driver class with `Class.forName()`, that driver registers itself with the driver manager. You can do this with as many drivers as you want.

The first parameter of `getConnection()` is a URL that will uniquely identify the driver to use for that connection.

However, rather than getting connections directly from the driver manager, I recommend that you use a connection pool (such as [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)). This will let you get connections on an as-needed basis, and will provide some additional functionality such as warning you if you forget to return the connection to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DataSource`. Configure a `DataSource` for each type of connection and the use the appropriate `DataSource` each time (e.g. via the proper `DAO`)