# How class.forname() registers drivers. How does it work internally?

Tags: java, jdbc

In my project I have to connect to two different databases. Eg MySQL and postgres.
How do drivermanager know which driver implementation to load.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use multiple JDBC drivers in the same application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945289/how-to-use-multiple-jdbc-drivers-in-the-same-application)

Comment: In most common uses of JDBC you no longer need to load the driver explicitly. Because it is either loaded by automatic driver loading, or by the datasource you use.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC finds all drivers through SPI and register them, when you create a connection, driver manager trys all registered drivers and return the first successful created one.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName` initialises the named class. (Unless you use the three-arg form with `false`.) The class has code in its static initialiser that registers a `Driver` instance with the `DriverManager`.

When opening a connection, the `DriverManager` searches through the currently registered `Driver`s to find one that can match the connection URL and is accessible to the caller class. (Accessible means the caller class' class loader is a descendent of the driver class' class loader. The opposite way things usually work because the driver is a service.)

Both mutable statics (a.k.a. globals) and walking the stack to find calling classes is extremely bad practice, but it was an early API of its type.